# Converting Formula from Formula Bar to VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Anyone knows how to convert this piece of formula to VBA code ? Here is the code : `=S4&(AA5&AA6&AA7&AA8&AA9&AA10)`. If I try to convert it to VBA, which is as follows:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1")
ws.Range("S4") & = ws.Range("AA5") &
```

I always encounter an error. Then I've tried this:

```
ws.Range("S4&") = ws.Range("AA5&")
```

Then I don't know what to do next. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: @TheGuyThatDoesn'tKnowMuch I've updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub fhskjdfh()
    Dim s As String
    s = [S4] & [AA5] & [AA6] & [AA7] & [AA8] & [AA9] & [AA10]
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Based on your edit, try this instead:

```
Sub fhskjdfh()
    [S4] = [AA5] & [AA6] & [AA7] & [AA8] & [AA9] & [AA10]
End Sub
```

Comment: But it's not working. I've updated my question for more information. Thanks!